# How to update cell in row in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can i update the the row of particular cell in the table when button of that row is clicked. I tried
but it does not work.

```
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="news">5</td>
        <td id="name">James</td>
        <td><button onclick="update_value(event)">Update value</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="news">6</td>
        <td id="name">Nayome</td>
        <td><button onclick="update_value(event)">Update value</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="news">9</td>
        <td id="name">Adrlin</td>
        <td><button onclick="update_value(event)">Update value</button></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

function update_value(event) {
    let clickedElem = event.target;
    let newValue = 88;
    let newName = Radi;
    event.target.id.value = newValue;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');

table.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const button = e.target.closest('button');
  
  if (!button) return;
  
  const parent = button.closest('tr');
  const news = parent.querySelector('.news');
  
  news.innerHTML = 1 + Math.floor((99 - 1) * Math.random());
});
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="news">5</td>
        <td class="name">James</td>
        <td><button>Update value</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="news">6</td>
        <td class="name">Nayome</td>
        <td><button>Update value</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="news">9</td>
        <td class="name">Adrlin</td>
        <td><button>Update value</button></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

> Is there way we can solve this issue on button click instead addding
> addEventListener on table

```js
const updateCell = (node) => {
  const parent = node.closest('tr');
  const news = parent.querySelector('.news');
  
  news.innerHTML = 1 + Math.floor((99 - 1) * Math.random());
};
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="news">5</td>
        <td class="name">James</td>
        <td><button onclick="updateCell(this)">Update value</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="news">6</td>
        <td class="name">Nayome</td>
        <td><button onclick="updateCell(this)">Update value</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="news">9</td>
        <td class="name">Adrlin</td>
        <td><button onclick="updateCell(this)">Update value</button></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: While this code does answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Is there way we can solve this issue on button click instead addding ```addEventListener``` on table

Answer (score 0):

In the `html` code the `id`-s need to be changed to `class` because if there are multiple `html` elements with the same `id`, the `html` will be invalid.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="news">5</td>
            <td class="name">James</td>
            <td><button onclick="update_value(event)">Update value</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="news">6</td>
            <td class="name">Nayome</td>
            <td><button onclick="update_value(event)">Update value</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="news">9</td>
            <td class="name">Adrlin</td>
            <td><button onclick="update_value(event)">Update value</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the `JavaScript` code we need to find the parent `tr` element. Using the `tr` element we can find its children based on `name` and `news` class. The `newName` variable should be assigned with a `string` or the `Radi` variable should already exist with an assigned value. In my example, I used a `string` simply. Finally, the `innerHTML` of the two elements can be updated.

```
function update_value(event) {
     let clickedElem = event.target;
     let trElement = clickedElem.closest("tr");
     let nameElement = trElement.querySelector(".name");
     let newsElement = trElement.querySelector(".news");
     let newValue = 88;
     let newName = "Radi";
     newsElement.innerHTML = newValue;
     nameElement.innerHTML = newName;
}
```